# In latex, how to make all the WBS activities in Gantt chart align left?

Tags: latex

I am writing a Gantt chart in latex. But the activities on the left do not align left. So can anybody tells me how can I make all the WBS activities in Gantt Chart align left in latex? Thank you very much! Here is the code of latex:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % turn hyphenation off by default
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Risk Analysis}

\section{Project Plan}
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
% \renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}
\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{START-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{FINISH-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-f}{FINISH-TO-FINISH}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
{
\sffamily
\begin{ganttchart}[
    canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
    include title in canvas=false,
    bar label font=\mdseries\small\color{black!70},
    bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
    bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
    group incomplete/.append style={fill=groupblue},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group height=.5,
    group peaks tip position=0,
    group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
    group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
    link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, linkred},
    link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries,
    link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt}
  ]{1}{14}
  \gantttitle[
    title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and -3pt}
  ]{WEEKS:\quad1}{1}
  \gantttitlelist{2,...,14}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup[progress=0]{WBS 1 More Research}{1}{1}\\
  \ganttgroup[progress=0]{WBS 2 Speaker Verification}{2}{3} \\
\end{ganttchart}
}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I make all the WBS activities align left? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give all your WBS activities a fixed text width, e.g. `group label node/.append style={text width=5.5cm}`,  they will automatically be left aligned:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % turn hyphenation off by default
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Risk Analysis}

\section{Project Plan}
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
% \renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}
\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{START-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{FINISH-TO-START}
\setganttlinklabel{f-f}{FINISH-TO-FINISH}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
{
\sffamily
\begin{ganttchart}[
    canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
    include title in canvas=false,
    bar label font=\mdseries\small\color{black!70},
    bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
    bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
    group incomplete/.append style={fill=groupblue},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group height=.5,
    group peaks tip position=0,
%    group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
    group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
    link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, linkred},
    link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries,
    link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt},
    group label node/.append style={text width=5.5cm},
  ]{1}{14}
  \gantttitle[
    title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and -3pt}
  ]{WEEKS:\quad1}{1}
  \gantttitlelist{2,...,14}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup[progress=0]{WBS 1 More Research}{1}{1}\\
  \ganttgroup[progress=0]{WBS 2 Speaker Verification}{2}{3} \\
\end{ganttchart}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!